# Finding summation of sum of two limits , if one of the limits does not exist .

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, summation

> Find
> $$
> \sum_{a=-10}^{12}\left(\lim _{x \to a} \frac{a}{\pi x^2}+\lim _{t \to 0} \frac{2 a}{\pi} \tan ^{-1} \frac{a}{t}\right)
> $$

the second limit does not exits because it can be $\pm a$ from different sides.
Now even if we take $t \to 0^+$ then also how we can calculate summation because the first limit will be $1/\pi$ a and it will cease to exit at $a=0$.

Comment: why do you think this exists?

Comment: to answer the first comment pi = 3.14. and for the second comment the answer is given to be 144.50

Comment: I would express both limits as a Taylor series and see if some terms nicely cancel out

Comment: yes I am sorry I edited it ! I dont think that can help!

Comment: If the limits don't exist, then the sum of the limits doesn't exist either. Where does this expression come from, and why do you think it should have a value?